# PlayN Samples: git clone command throws error: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Tags: git, sample, playn

I'm trying to follow the GettingStarted instructions for PlayN.

I get an error when trying to clone the repository:

```
Macintosh: test dev $ git clone https://code.google.com/p/playn-samples    
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/dev/test/playn-samples/.git/
fatal: https://code.google.com/p/playn-samples/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

Is this a problem on the git server, or is there something I need to do on my end to get this command to work?

---

Update:
I was able to fix this problem by updating my git client from 1.6.5.2 to 1.7.7.3

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen when you have a misconfigured `.netrc` file. Do you have a `~/.netrc` file? If so, try renaming it to something else and reissuing the `git clone` command.

If that works, then you should make sure your `.netrc` contains only valid entries, and if it contains an entry for `code.google.com`, be sure it contains your correct Google Code password. A valid `.netrc` entry has the form:

```
machine HOSTNAME login USERNAME password PASSWORD
```

where HOSTNAME, USERNAME and PASSWORD are replaced with appropriate values for a given account.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried it but it did not solve my problem. I fixed my problem by updating my git client from 1.6.5.2 to 1.7.7.3.